# Finding a row sums of a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

I want to find the sum of the first row and second row of a 2D array of integers. This is my code and is there any way I can make this code shorter?

```java
//creating 2D array for integers
int[][] num = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;

//sum for first row
for (int a = 0; a == 0; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
        sum1 += num[a][b];
    }
    System.out.println(sum1);
}

//sum for second row
for (int a = 1; a == 1; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
        sum2 += num[a][b];
    }
    System.out.println(sum2);
}
```

Output is:

```
6
15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```java
int[][] num = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

for (int a = 0; a <= 1; a++) {
    int sum1 = 0;
    for (int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
        sum1 += num[a][b];
    }
    System.out.println(sum1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use streams to get an array of row sums of a 2d array as follows:

```java
int[][] num = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

int[] sum = Arrays.stream(num)
        .map(Arrays::stream)
        .mapToInt(IntStream::sum)
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sum)); // [6, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```java
int[][] num = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};

int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;

//sum for first row and second row
for (int a = 0; a <= 1; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
        if (a == 0)
            sum1 += num[a][b];
        else
            sum2 += num[a][b];
    }
}
System.out.println(sum1); // 6
System.out.println(sum2); // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

- The outer loop in both instances is redundant, since it basically only deals as a variable declaration & initialization. This loop is not needed since it is only run once anyways.
- You should also not use fixed sizes for your loops, as this will break your code once you alter the size of your array.
- Also, I would suggest you use an array to store the sum for each row.

Example with all the suggestions:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] nums = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
    // hold the sum of each row in an array
    int[] sums = new int[nums.length];
    // loops shouldn't use fixed sizes, they
    // should run according to the arrays size
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; j++) {
            // for each row, calculate the sum
            // and store it in the sum array
            sums[i] += nums[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sums));
}
```

Output:

```
[6, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think about 2D array as an array of arrays.

You can simply iterate over the "big array" (lets call the index `i`) and then take the array on the `i` place and iterate over him (lets call the index `j`).

Now you can simply sum up the value on place `[i][j]` with the current value of a 0 initialized variable (lets call it `sum`).
in java:

```java
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; i++)
        sum += array[i][j];
}
// Output: 21
```

Or if you want to print only the sub arrays sum you can print the sum and initialize it when the second loop finished:

```java
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; i++)
        sum += array[i][j];
    System.out.println(sum);
    sum = 0;
}
// Output:
// 6
// 15
```

Comment: Thanks for this, now I learned that sub arrays exist.

Answer (score 0):

Because we're going to go through all the elements, in terms of time, `O(n)` is the optimal time complexity.

```java
int sum1 = 0;
int sum2 = 0;

//sum for first row
for (int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
    sum1 += num[0][b];
}
System.out.println(sum1);

//sum for second row
for (int b = 0; b <= 2; b++) {
    sum2 += num[1][b];
}
System.out.println(sum2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Streams API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

int[][] num = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 }
};

// sum of all elements in the 2D array
int sum = Arrays.stream(num).mapToInt(a -> IntStream.of(a).sum()).sum();
```

This sums all elements of the 2D array. This way your code sums the entire grid even if you add more rows or add more elements to each row.

If you need the sum of each row separately, consider this:

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

int[][] num = {
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 4, 5, 6 }
};

// sum of the first row
int sum1 = IntStream.of(num[0]).sum();

// sum of the second row
int sum2 = IntStream.of(num[1]).sum();
```

Comment: But that would sum all values of the complete 2D array, not row-wise as OP requires.

Comment: @maloomeister Yes, I pointed this out in my answer. Thought it might be helpful anyways.